# Correct way to update byId and allIds in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my state shape:

```
export default {
    app: {
        loading: false,
        loadError: null
    },
    search: {
        type: null,
        text: ''
    },
    things: {
        byId: {

        },
        allIds: []
    }
}
```

When I fetch new `things` from the server, I want to update both `things.byId` and `things.allIds` - as recommended by Redux docs. I'm doing it in the following way but I feel like there's a better way:

```
import { LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS } from '../actions/actionTypes'
import initialState from './initialState'

export default function things(state = initialState.things, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS:
            const thingsById = {}
            action.things.forEach(thing => {
                thingsById[thing.id] = thing
            })
            return {
                ...state,
                byId: thingsById,
                allIds: action.things.map(thing => thing.id)
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I'm using `combineReducers` and the above `reducers/things.js` is one of them. The part I'm concerned about is `action.things.forEach...` I have a feeling there's a cleaner / more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: That's actually fine. You could use [lodash.keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy) if you feel like using an external implementation or if you are already using lodash in your project

Comment: @Lucas thanks for the reassurance

Comment: @Carpefitzz What I would change though (and I believe it's more cleaner/efficient) is to break `byId` and `allIds` in separate reducers. And have `things = combineReducers({ byId, allIds })` but that's not what you asked :D

Comment: @Lucas that seems like the right way to do it - thank you! Feel free to post it as an answer so I can give you credit for it